# Running Sidekiq inside Docker - Handle termination of Docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, sidekiq

I'm using Rails + Sidekiq + Docker. I plan to deploy my Sidekiq process inside a Docker container. My jobs are quite long-running and have unpredictable durations (basically it's executing a long-running query against the database - can be up to 10-15 mins)

When I kill my docker container (as part of a new deployment), how I can tell Sidekiq to gracefully stop so that no existing jobs are interrupted?

Has anyone faced similar situation before. If so, how do you work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker stop -t XX` should send the TERM signal to tell Sidekiq to shutdown and wait XX seconds.

You'll want to extend Sidekiq's hard timeout too with `sidekiq -t XX`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this works. I just realized that my jobs are a lot more long-runinng and unpredict than stated (edited the original question). Was looking to see if anyone has any clever ways of doing so. But it seems that this is the correct and proper way to do it.